# Is there a way to search github issues for "approved" status?

Tags: github

Specifically, I would like to list PR's across multiple repos, but exclude those that I've already approved.  I know how to do all but the last part, using a query like:

`is:open is:pr repo:myorg/repo1 repo:myorg/repo2`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this doesn't exist by using just a search query.

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-github/#types-of-searches

Would you be willing to use the GitHub API?